# How can I load multiple stylesheets with foreach loop

Tags: loops, foreach, stylesheet

I am trying to load two stylesheets in HTML using PHP (style.css) & (normalize.css) plus a font-url using foreach loops but I can't quite figure out how to do this, I would love any help you guys could give. Cheers

Comment: I have a variable in my index.php file...

$stylesheets = ["css/normalize.css", "font-url", "css/style.css"];

and I want to load all of them using a loop

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figured it out. If anyone else is wondering this is how I do it

```
    foreach($stylesheets as $stylesheet){
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $stylesheet . '">';
    }
```